# How to create a painting application using PHP and HTML 5?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a website for painting and it should look like MS Paint. Is it possible to create same in PHP or HTML 5?

- I don't know where to start. I am not asking for script or code.
- I just need reference. So I'll start creating something like that.
- I want to create same form and painting options like MS Paint.

Comment: http://www.bindows.net/demos/

Comment: Thanks Matias. It is very nice. Need to do some research.

Comment: @Matias if i used the Bindows then Hosting provider will allow us to host it? any idea.

Comment: I believe you don't need any permission in your hosting environment, because it's just a client-side technology (plain JavaScript and HTML).

Comment: This is an interesting project, but the question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. The answer to all "how do I start" questions is "have you broken it down into achievable/searchable pieces".

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this through `HTML5 Canvas`, below are some good examples:
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355230/HTML-Canvas-A-Simple-Paint-Program-Touch-and-Mou

Answer (score 1):

All you need would be a html code with some forms, canvas and javascript.

The forms would be for all your buttons to controll the functions:
[learn about them here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

The canvas would be for the drawing area: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486691/how-to-do-coloring-in-images-jpg-gif-png)

You can learn about javascript functions [on this page](http://www.functionx.com/javascript/Lesson05.htm)

for ultimate knowledge about javascript i can recommend [codeacedemy](http://www.codecademy.com/)